# Whenever I am doing any exercise on Opportunity object I also get the error Ilegal assignment from list<Opportunity>to list<Opportunity>

Tags: apex, list

`List<Opportunity> oppList =[ Select Name, StageName, CloseDate from Opportunity];`

Comment: You have to specify the type of your list using : List<Opportunity> oppList

Comment: @MartinLezer The `<type>` part isn't rendered by the stackexchange software because it looks too much like html, but if you go to edit the question, you'll see it is indeed there. Just an issue of not formatting as code.

Comment: Works for me when I copy-paste this exact code and execute via anonymous apex. You'll need to [edit] your question to provide more details.

Comment: Do you have an Apex class named "Opportunity"?  If so, you need to rename it.